# Getting invalid verification code for email confirmation

Tags: craft3, craft-pro

I am using Craft CMS as a backend for react Next app. On our live site we are sometimes getting complaints from the user about error when user try to verify code sent in the email.

This case doesn't happen with every user but very for random users. For this reason I am not able to find the reason for the issue and fix it.
Everytime I see following information in the log file.

> 2020-05-27 10:17:35 [-][-][-][warning][craft\services\Users::isVerificationCodeValidForUser] The verification code (gqkZpvgTZDMNSXRyNuXE4ksxpNOlBOl) given for userId: 99965 does not match the hash in the database.
>   2020-05-27 10:17:35 [-][-][-][info][application] $_GET = [
>       'p' => 'ACT/craft-rest-api/user/verify-email'
>       'code' => 'gqkZpvgTZDMNSXRyNuXE4ksxpNOlBOl'
>       'id' => 'ef2156d6-306b-4a88-80bb-25ca26562702'
>   ]

Here is the information about the system.

PHP version 7.4.5

OS version  Linux 3.10.0-1127.el7.x86_64

Database driver & version   MySQL 8.0.20

Image driver & version  GD 7.4.5

Craft edition & version Craft Pro 3.4.21

Yii version 2.0.35

Twig version    2.12.5

Guzzle version  6.5.4

Imagine version 1.2.3-dev

Plugins:-

Amazon S3   1.2.8

Architect   2.3.3

CKEditor    1.0.0-beta.3

Comments    1.5.6

Contact Form    2.2.7

Craft-Rest-Api  1.1.0

Enforce password    1.0.0

Image Resizer   2.0.9

Klaviyo Connect 3.1.3.2

Redactor    2.6.1

SendGrid    1.2.0

Comment: What's ``verificationCodeDuration`` set to?

Answer (score 1):

Those codes are valid for as long as whatever [verificationCodeDuration](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html#verificationcodeduration) is set to (24 hours by default).

Guessing the users that are getting that are hitting expired verification codes.